# SL4: Databind to property on view model, are binding objects notified when the ViewModel changes?

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0

SL4, MVVM.  Our MainView has a corresponding MainViewModel as its DataContext.
MainViewModel has a ThingViewModel for a property -- CurrentThingViewModel .

We bind a CheckBox in the MainView to a property of ThingViewModel:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CurrentThingViewModel.ReadOnly, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

When a differnt ThingViewModel is assigned to CurrentThingViewModel, CTVM raises a PropertyChanged event.  Does the CheckBox get notified, since it is bound to the property of CTVM, and not the property actually raising the PropertyChanged event?

Thanks for any insights...

Comment: An experiment with a very simple project suggests that the view bound to CTVM.ReadOnly will be updated when a different ThingViewModel is assigned to CTVM.
Something else must be going on -- maybe some confusion in that the checkbox.IsChecked gets set programmatically as well as by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the binding will listen for a PropertyChanged event on all levels of the provided binding, if the first level binding is updating, all lower level bindings are trigerred as well.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding X.Y.Z, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The binding will check the value of X.Y.Z if PropertyChanged events are fired on either X, Y or Z